# Creating an ArrayList that outputs into 2 types

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

Trying to create an Event ArrayList that creates Lectures and Talks. I'm not sure how to output the ArrayList to sort between the two. Seen below if the eventChoice is = 1 it creates a Talk and if 2 a Lecture.

```
if(eventChoice == 1){
                        System.out.println("Enter the title of the talk: "); 
                        title = scnr.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("\n"); 

                        System.out.println("Enter the start time"); 
                        System.out.println("Hour (0-23)"); 
                        int hour = scnr.nextInt(); 
                        System.out.println("Minute (0-59"); 
                        int minute = scnr.nextInt();

                        System.out.println("Enter duration"); 
                        int duration = scnr.nextInt();

                        Time startTime = new Time(hour,minute);
                        Time endTime = new Time((startTime.getHour() + duration/60), (startTime.getMinute() + duration%60));
                        Event e1 = new Event(title, startTime, endTime);
                        events.add(e1);
                    }

                    else if(eventChoice == 2){
                        System.out.println("Enter the title of the lecture: "); 
                        title = scnr.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("\n"); 

                        System.out.println("Enter the start time"); 
                        System.out.println("Hour (0-23)"); 
                        int hour = scnr.nextInt(); 
                        System.out.println("Minute (0-59"); 
                        int minute = scnr.nextInt();
                        int duration = 60;
                        Time startTime = new Time(hour,minute);
                        Time endTime = new Time((startTime.getHour()), (startTime.getMinute() + duration));
                        Event e1 = new Event(title, startTime, endTime);
                        events.add(e1);
                    }
```

Then in my event class I have

```
@Override
public String toString(){
            return String.format (": "+  getTitle()+ " ("+ getStartTime() + " to "+ getendTime() + " )");
       }
}
```

I was wondering what method I could use to output the array with the event type before the getTitle() If I try defining the types in the choices it outputs as null.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is **wrong** modelling. If you have different *Event* types, then don't use a single common class to represent those!

Instead: create a base class Event that provides the means to deal with title, start and end time.

And then create specific subclasses that handle those things differently that require different handling.

The design principle behind that is called ["Tell don't Ask"](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html): in OO programming you rarely/never query some object about its internal state to then make decisions. Instead, you simply call some method on that object.

And in your case, that would mean that you have subclasses for Talk versus Lecture which come with different toString() methods.

Finally: using an int and a switch to determine the event type is bad practice, too. At least: use some java **enum** instead of ints!

Answer (score 1):

In the `Event` class, add another field called `type` and add a getter for it:

```
private EventType type;
public EventType getType() {
    return type;
}
```

where `EventType` is declared as:

```
public enum EventType {
    Talk, Lecture
}
```

Add initialization for `type` in the constructor as well:

```
                 add this
                   |
                   V
public Event(EventType type, String title, Time startTime, Time endTime) {
    this.type = type; // <---- and this
    // ...
}
```

Change the `toString` method to:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return getType() + ": "+  getTitle()+ " ("+ getStartTime() + " to "+ getendTime() + " )");
}
```

Your code should look like this:

```
if(eventChoice == 1){
    System.out.println("Enter the title of the talk: ");
    title = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("Enter the start time");
    System.out.println("Hour (0-23)");
    int hour = scnr.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Minute (0-59");
    int minute = scnr.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter duration");
    int duration = scnr.nextInt();

    Time startTime = new Time(hour,minute);
    Time endTime = new Time((startTime.getHour() + duration/60), (startTime.getMinute() + duration%60));
    Event e1 = new Event(EventType.Talk, title, startTime, endTime);
    events.add(e1);
}

else if(eventChoice == 2){
    System.out.println("Enter the title of the lecture: ");
    title = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("Enter the start time");
    System.out.println("Hour (0-23)");
    int hour = scnr.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Minute (0-59");
    int minute = scnr.nextInt();
    int duration = 60;
    Time startTime = new Time(hour,minute);
    Time endTime = new Time((startTime.getHour()), (startTime.getMinute() + duration));
    Event e1 = new Event(EventType.Lecture, title, startTime, endTime);
    events.add(e1);
}
```

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the reminder! I didn't consider that when I was writing the answer. Fixed now!

Comment: Great ;-) now lets see what he makes out of those answers.